# Start all functions in one line

Tags: python-2.7, function

Is there any way to run all functions in python in one line instead of calling them one by one .
Ex :
fun1()

fun2()

fun3()

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what is the purpose of the question, however if it helps you you can make a list of the return values:

```
[fun1(), fun2(),...]
```